# Condense cross references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) package sorts and compresses cross-references. It also automatically determines the format of references, so that you don't have to type "equation" in the source. However the standard output is space wasting. In the example is references equations like `eqs. (1), (2) and (4) to (6)`, however I want the shorter expression `eqs. (1,2,4-6)`. I am not forced to use the package `cleveref` but I am not aware of an alternative.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
equation 1\label{eq1}\\
equation 2\label{eq2}\\
equation 3\label{eq3}\\
equation 4\label{eq4}\\
equation 5\label{eq5}\\
equation 6\label{eq6}
\end{align}
\\
output of cleveref is \cref{eq2,eq4,eq1,eq5,eq6}\\
I want: eqs.\~(1,2,4-6)
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should look at sections 8.2.2 and 8.2.3 of the cleveref manual. The examples given are in terms of equation numbers, so should be fairly simple to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- added the commands `\crefmultiformat`, `\crefrangemultiformat` and `\crefrangeformat` (see [`cleverref` manual](https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) 8.2.2 "Reference Ranges" and 8.2.3 "Multiple Cross-References")
- added some test cases
- (I would recommend using a space after the comma)

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefmultiformat{equation}{eqs.~(#2#1#3}%
{,#2#1#3)}{,#2#1#3}{,#2#1#3)}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{eqs.~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6}%
{,#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}{,#3#1#4--#5#2#6}{,#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{eqs.~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
equation 1\label{eq1}\\
equation 2\label{eq2}\\
equation 3\label{eq3}\\
equation 4\label{eq4}\\
equation 5\label{eq5}\\
equation 6\label{eq6}
\end{align}
\\
output of cleveref is \cref{eq2,eq4,eq1,eq5,eq6}\\
I want: eqs.~(1,2,4-6)\\
Some tests:\\
\cref{eq4,eq5,eq6}\\
\cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq6}\\
\cref{eq1,eq3}\\
\cref{eq1,eq3,eq4}\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? Note that LuaLaTeX is used solely to speed up the process of creating six equation-related `\label` instructions.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,}
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{eqs.~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{eqs.~(#2#1#3}{,#2#1#3)}{,#2#1#3}{,#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}
% create 6 equation-related \label instructions programmatically:
\directlua{
  for i=1,6 do tex.sprint ( '\\refstepcounter{equation}\\label{eq'..i..'}' ) end  
}

\obeylines
eqs.~(1,2,4--6) -- hard-coded
\cref{eq2,eq4,eq1,eq5,eq6} -- with \texttt{\string\cref}
\smallskip
\cref{eq1}
\cref{eq1,eq3}
\cref{eq2,eq4,eq3}
\crefrange{eq1}{eq5}

\end{document}
```